# How to get my View set in the Content Presenter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently working on a database-based application for work and I am struggling with connecting the ViewModel methods to my view. Here is what I've got so far:

```cs
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand SwitchViewsCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SwitchViewsCommand = new RelayCommand((parameter) => CurrentView = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(parameter as Type));
    }
    private UserControl _currentView;
    public UserControl CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentView;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentView)
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainViewModel and following my Xaml-Code

```
<Window x:Class="sKillPase.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:sKillPase.Core.ViewModels;assembly=sKillPase.Core" xmlns:view="clr-namespace:sKillPase.View"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sKillPase.View"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:MainViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1200">
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Black" ></Border>
    <Border x:Name="Buttons" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Black"></Border>
    <Border x:Name="Content" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="#FF303030"></Border>
    <Border x:Name="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="Black"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ContentArea" Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button x:Name="Data" 
                Command="{Binding SwitchViewsCommand }" 
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:DataView}" 
                >
            Daten bearbeiten
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="Report"
                Command="{Binding SwitchViewsCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{x:Type viewmodels:ReportViewModel}"
                >
            Report erstellen
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

So my problem is, that if I compile the application, the Content Presenter doesn't show anything. It stays completely empty. So what can I do to add the different views (which I declared as User Controls) to my Content Presenter, by pressing one of the two buttons?

Furthermore, one of the views contains a data grid that shows the different tables of my database. So if I have to watch out for some problems regarding the database, please feel free to state.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You couod change the viewmodel rather than the view and use datatemplating to associate your usercontrol with it's view.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it out and update my question soon :)